# Subset and replace data in a named list of tibbles: how to get the index, subset and keep the list format and structure?

Tags: r

I am much more familiar with vectors, data.frames and such but agree it comes handy to use list when a function has multiple outputs.

A function from a package I am using retrieves a named list of tibbles (not so familiar with tibbles) nor list.

```
    List of 68
 $ 292684 :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ name: chr [1:5] "Animalia" "Arthropoda" "Chelicerata" "Arachnida" ...
  ..$ rank: chr [1:5] "Kingdom" "Phylum" "Subphylum" "Class" ...
  ..$ id  : int [1:5] 2 1065 1274 1300 292684
 $ 126752 :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ name: chr [1:10] "Animalia" "Chordata" "Vertebrata" "Gnathostomata" ...
  ..$ rank: chr [1:10] "Kingdom" "Phylum" "Subphylum" "Superclass" ...
  ..$ id  : int [1:10] 2 1821 146419 1828 10194 11014 151729 125516 125909 126752
```

My question is **how to navigate efficiently this list, subset according to a logical condition, maybe replace some values while maintaining the list format?**

I have tried unlist()/relist() but it doesn't keep the structure.
I have tried nested sapply  sapply(sapply(mylist, "[",2), function(x) whatever) and then applied my condition on the output to identify the position and use an eval(parse(paste...) to reach the correct level in the list but rather get tricky...

```
 aa <- sapply(sapply(list.classif, "[", 2), length)
 who.max <- which(aa==max(aa))
 pos.list <- which(aa==max(aa))
 index <- names(who.max)
 best.classif <- eval(parse(text=paste("list.classif[pos.list]$`",index, 
 "`$rank", sep="") ))
```

If I managed to subset data that way... It seems too complex and I am sure there is a better solution?

Also, **what if I want to replace data at this specific location?**
You can't do the classic object, can't you?

```
object[index, index] <- replacebythat
```

---

Possible operations could be:

- to change "Chordata" into... "Whatever",
- change "Class" into... "Something"
- Identify which organisms have a "Subphylum" "Crustacea" (so $name== Crustacea)
- Based on the selections above, change an information.

---

SAMPLE OF THE DATASET with dput()

```
    structure(list(`292684` = structure(list(name = c("Animalia", 
"Arthropoda", "Chelicerata", "Arachnida", "Acari"), rank = c("Kingdom", 
"Phylum", "Subphylum", "Class", "Subclass"), id = c(2L, 1065L, 
1274L, 1300L, 292684L)), .Names = c("name", "rank", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `126752` = structure(list(
    name = c("Animalia", "Chordata", "Vertebrata", "Gnathostomata", 
    "Pisces", "Actinopterygii", "Perciformes", "Trachinoidei", 
    "Ammodytidae", "Ammodytes", "Ammodytes tobianus"), rank = c("Kingdom", 
    "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Superclass", "Class", 
    "Order", "Suborder", "Family", "Genus", "Species"), id = c(2L, 
    1821L, 146419L, 1828L, 11676L, 10194L, 11014L, 151729L, 125516L, 
    125909L, 126752L)), .Names = c("name", "rank", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `421139` = structure(list(
    name = c("Animalia", "Arthropoda", "Crustacea", "Multicrustacea", 
    "Hexanauplia", "Thecostraca", "Cirripedia", "Thoracica", 
    "Sessilia", "Balanomorpha", "Balanoidea", "Balanidae", "Amphibalaninae", 
    "Amphibalanus", "Amphibalanus improvisus"), rank = c("Kingdom", 
    "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Subclass", 
    "Infraclass", "Superorder", "Order", "Suborder", "Superfamily", 
    "Family", "Subfamily", "Genus", "Species"), id = c(2L, 1065L, 
    1066L, 845959L, 889925L, 22388L, 1082L, 1107L, 106033L, 106039L, 
    106041L, 106057L, 394026L, 415046L, 421139L)), .Names = c("name", 
"rank", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), `1135` = structure(list(name = c("Animalia", 
"Arthropoda", "Crustacea", "Multicrustacea", "Malacostraca", 
"Eumalacostraca", "Peracarida", "Amphipoda"), rank = c("Kingdom", 
"Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Subclass", "Superorder", 
"Order"), id = c(2L, 1065L, 1066L, 845959L, 1071L, 1086L, 1090L, 
1135L)), .Names = c("name", "rank", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `103068` = structure(list(
    name = c("Animalia", "Arthropoda", "Crustacea", "Multicrustacea", 
    "Malacostraca", "Eumalacostraca", "Peracarida", "Amphipoda", 
    "Senticaudata", "Gammarida", "Gammaridira", "Gammaroidea", 
    "Bathyporeiidae", "Bathyporeia", "Bathyporeia pilosa"), rank = c("Kingdom", 
    "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Subclass", 
    "Superorder", "Order", "Suborder", "Infraorder", "Parvorder", 
    "Superfamily", "Family", "Genus", "Species"), id = c(2L, 
    1065L, 1066L, 845959L, 1071L, 1086L, 1090L, 1135L, 719424L, 
    236816L, 720166L, 720708L, 533675L, 101742L, 103068L)), .Names = c("name", 
"rank", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))), .Names = c("292684", "126752", "421139", "1135", 
"103068"))
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of your data with `dput()` function and specify what operation do you want to perform?

Comment: Ohh cool function! I always wondered how to provide a good example :D
I will post it in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for - to change "Chordata" into... "Whatever" :

```
library(tidyverse)

lot %>%
  map(~ .x %>% mutate(name = if_else(name == 'Chordata', 'Whatever', name)))
```

Answer for - Identify which organisms have a "Subphylum" "Crustacea" (so $name== Crustacea) :

```
lot %>%
  map(~ .x %>% filter(
    name == 'Crustacea'
  ))
```

Comment: I had never tried with pipelines :D Just getting to it. Seems to do the job.
I guess I'll have to start using it more.

Comment: Chabros how would you combine?
For instance, if the $rank  is a "Subphylum", mutate $name to "Something".
Thanks already! It seems so easy and clear with the pipes.